# How to disable unread group notifications in Whatsapp?

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.2-jelly-bean, whatsapp-messenger

The "mute" option allows you to stop receiving notifications. However, I can still see the number of unread messages for a group that has been previously muted.

In addition, this group keeps coming at the top of the list of groups every time a new message is sent to it.

Is there a way to disable this without having to leave a group?

[image]

Comment: Sadly, you cannot.

Comment: It is now possible if your device is rooted, check out ShutApp below.

Comment: @EladNava Not working for Android 6.0+.

Comment: You need a rooted device. It does work on Android 6.0+.

Comment: @EladNava  I have a rooted device. Its not working. I have Lineage OS 14.1 based on Android 7.1.1.

Comment: This issue has been bugging me for ages. It is very disappointing that the whatsapp team refuses to address it.

Answer (score 13):

This issue has been plaguing Whatsapp since its inception. I have had long email conversations with their support team on multiple occasions. Even uploaded a detailed video explaining the bug:
Check it out here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bldIuA-OjU
This was their reply after about about 20 emails explaining the issue.[image]

I gave up after that. To anyone reading this, please see the video to understand the problem. If someone influential can publicise it, maybe the will fix it then.

Comment: The developers left this annoyance open deliberately to keep users returning to Whatsapp, disabling it would reduce the user traffic dramatically (More active users = more $). Hopefully enough people will demand for a fix or someone will be able to make a workaround externally.

Comment: I developed an external workaround, see the ShutApp answer below.

Answer (score 5):

### ShutApp

ShutApp is an Android app I developed for **rooted devices** that will automatically mark your muted WhatsApp chats as read and prevent them from jumping to the top of the chat list, so that you don't have to leave those annoying groups.

You do need a **rooted** android device to use the app, though. That's because the app needs to be able to modify WhatsApp's internal database which is not accessible to other apps without granting root access.

ShutApp is completely free and open source, and if your phone isn't rooted yet, I think it's definitely worth rooting in order to use this app!

https://github.com/eladnava/shutapp-android

Comment: How to download?

Comment: Check out usage docs: https://github.com/eladnava/shutapp-android#usage

Comment: App not working for me (Lineage OS 14.1).

Comment: You need a rooted device. It does work on Android 6.0+.

Comment: I have a rooted device. Its not working. I have Lineage OS 14.1 based on Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Open an issue in the project page: https://github.com/eladnava/shutapp-android/issues

Comment: I have opened an issue now.

Comment: It doesn't work on Rooted Moto G1 Nougat, I installed your App directly on the phone (without the USB commands), checked all permissions and messages keep pilling up on the top. Are you still updating it?

Comment: Open an issue in the project page: github.com/eladnava/shutapp-android/issues

Answer (score 0):

> You can mute a group for a specified period of time. You will still
>   receive the messages sent to the group, but your phone will not
>   vibrate or make noise you when they are received. To mute a group:
>
> Go to the group in WhatsApp.
>       Tap Menu Button > Mute Group.
>       Select how long you would like notifications to be muted.
>       Optionally, uncheck Show notifications to stop notifications from being shown in your notification slider.

From [whatsapp.com](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567#mute)
Your group will go on top because it has the newest message. That's how it works.

Comment: But should you **SEE** those messages in the notification shade once you receive a new message?? I guess not. That's unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The inquiry is about a disabling muted group notifications. Posting how to "mute" and reaffirming what was previously stated is hardly an answer.